# Список кортежей добавляю в БД. Задача, чтобы при добавлении списка в БД, строки которых нет в БД добавлялись, а которые есть обновляли значения

Tags: python, sql, sqlite3

Я знаю, что этот sql запрос не работает, но есть ли что-нибудь похожее, чтобы не использовать цикл for?

```
def add_in_base(self, list):
      with sqlite3.connect('weather.db') as db:
         cursor = db.cursor()
         sql = 'INSERT INTO weather (date, weather, temperature) values (?, ?, ?) ON 
                                    CONFLICT (date) DO UPDATE SET weather=? temperature=?;'
         cursor.executemany(sql, list)
```

Comment: Вставить данные во временную таблицу в **одной** транзакции (это важно! так будет очень быстро). Потом сделать insert из этой таблицы. [upsert](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) - в конце пример.

Comment: Я читал документацию по upsert, но ничего не получилось сделать. Приведите пожалуйста пример кода после транзакции во временную таблицу